# Google sheets send email with specified cells in row on 'checkbox' click

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a working script in google sheets which sends an email when checkbox status = "true" which I've so far only been able to include one cell in the row that corresponds with the checkbox. I need to be able to include the entire row (eg C:M) of cells on where the checkbox sits but I've not been able to get this to work. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

This works (only sends cell 'C' when conditions are met):

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var range = e.range;
  var col = range.getColumn();
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var edited_value = e.value;
  var ss = e.range.getSheet();


  if(col == 35 && edited_value == "TRUE" && ss.getRange("B"+row).getValue() == "") //go to a4
{
  Browser.msgBox("Check if you entered data")

}else
{

      var to = "xxxxxx@live.com"
      var subject = ss.getRange("B"+row).getValue();

     ** var Email_body = ss.getRange("C"+row).getValue();**
     
    
      MailApp.sendEmail(to, subject, Email_body);

      Browser.msgBox("Email Sent")
     
}
}
```

I have tried to experiment with calling on different combinations to include multiple cells to no avail, eg:

```
var Email_body = ss.getRange("C:M"+row).getValue()
var Email_body = ss.getRange[("C"+row)("D"+row)].getValue()
```

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var  Email_body = ss.getRange("C"+row+":M"+row).getValues()
```

would work I believe. You need use C3:M3 to specify the range not C:M3